# How to detect url from textbox like facebook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, user-interface

I am working on asp.net mvc3 application. in this I have a textarea where user can write url and paste url from that my code fetch url details on button click.

But I want to implement it like facebook. In facebook when we write some url it automatically fetch url details,

I tried keyup function but it will continuously checking input url.

```
 $('#urlinput').keyup(function () {
        //alert("something is here!!");
        if (!isValidURL($('#urlinput').val())) {
            alert('Please enter a valid url.');
            return false;
        }
        else {
        some code...
}
```

what I find in facebook is that when we write url followed by space it will fetch details of url and when we paste url in textbox it will fetch details of url. How can I implement like this?

can anybody suggest me what to do for implementing like Facebook?

Comment: is there a reason you are not closing your single quotes?

Comment: keyup is not the solution as it does not work when the user pastes a url with the mouse or browser's toolbar. It's more complicated than this if you want to catch all cases

Comment: @John: Yes you are right John.

Answer (score 1):

If I would be trying that I would do it this way:

1. In case I paste a URL using mouse, I would open the browser on mouseup event
2. In case I paste using keyboard, then it has to be CTRL + V ... so on CTRL keyup, i would fetch the URL
3. If Im typing then I would either go for keyup or when the textbox loses focus

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Pasting raises an event that you can bind to with:

```
$(myelement).bind('paste',function(event) {
    alert('paste');
});
```

Concerning the keyup event, the event object will provide the key that was pressed in `event.which`.

```
$(myelement).bind('keyup',function(event) {
    alert(event.which);
});
```

Using a regular expression, you can extract an url. You can find regex at this adress: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Now for the "preview" feature like on Facebook, i guess this is a bit more difficult as they seem to analyse the content of the target url to extract a thumbnail and some content (article text, etc).

Hope this helps,
d.

Comment: G: Thanks for your concern. I am done with Url extraction Like facebook. I just want to improve my code like facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do have to do it on `keyup`, maybe also on `onchange` to take care of situation when the user pastes the url.

When you recognize a valid url, you should send it to the server using AJAX. The server then downloads the url, and analyzing the HTML's string for data like page's title, and sanding this data back to client, where you can show it to the user.